# How can I display the current Search API filters to the user?

Tags: search

Using Search API and Facets on Drupal 9. If a user selects some filters (facets, text), how can we display the current search criteria to the user?

For example, similar to a breadcrumb list shows all of the current filters.

I seem to remember seeing this option before but cannot seem to find it now.

Comment: There’s a module included with facets for that isn’t there?  Used to be experimental, not sure if it still is

Comment: Yes, there is - it's the facets_summary submodule within the facets module. It provides a block to display a summary of the active facets.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. I had overlooked it without thinking about it because it's in an 'experimental' state. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The experimental sub-module for the Facets module call "Facets Summary" provides this functionality.